# Format Python String with BOM

Tags: python, email, byte-order-mark

I have a string that (I think) has BOM inside of it and I would like to remove all the BOM without messing with the format.

For example my string looks like this:

```
>=20
> =EF=BB=BF
>=20
> -Jeff
>=20
> Begin forwarded message:
>=20
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
>
>
>
> -Jeff
>
> Begin forwarded message:
>
```

I am fine with the `>` being left to indicate indention I just want the stray characters removed. If I decode the message then I get a string that is uglier and hard to read than what I already have. It has a bunch of `\r\n\r\n` in it from the line breaks so ideally id like to just remove the things mentioned leaving the format alone.

Edit 1:
Here is how I am getting to this point:

```
def getEmails():
    LOG.debug("Starting to get emails")
    conn = connectToMailServers()
    conn.select('inbox', readonly=True )
    result, data = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
    mail_ids = data[0]

    id_list = mail_ids.split()

    for _, i in enumerate(id_list):
        result, data = conn.fetch(str(int(i)), '(RFC822)' )
        for response_part in data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
                getPlainText(msg)

def getPlainText(msg):
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            LOG.debug(part.get_payload())
            return str(part.get_payload())
```

If I turn on decoding (`part.get_payload(decode=True)`) then I get into an issue of the string now having a bunch of `\r\n\r\n` so how can I do this without decode OR how can I reformat this into a formatted string removing the line breaks

Comment: how do you get this string? Maybe it is not BOM but HTML encoding - as I remeber `20` can means `space`

Comment: maybe you get `bytes` and you have to convert to `string` - ie. using `decode()`

Comment: Please see my edit 1 for the code im using.

Comment: @furas - The reason I thought it was BOM is because of things like `=EF=BB=BF` which led me to BOM references.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything. You're not calling `getEmails()`, but also your `getPlainText()` would only return a single result, which isn't even captured in `getEmails()`. So it's unclear what you mean when you say "your string looks like:" - how did you determine that? This may be a classic case of confusing what a variable looks like in the interpreter vs. what its actual value is / what it would look like when printed

Comment: I found that this is [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) and you can convert it to normal text using ie. `quopri.decodestring('=20 other text').decode()`. But `=EF=BB=BF` can be code for `BOM` - but after usingf `quopri` it doesn't show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly telling str converter to use UTF-8 worked,

`str(getPlainText(msg), "utf-8")`

Gave me the expected results I was looking for.